# Enter login form ASP.Net hind bottom login

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a login page by input ID and password and enter for login. I hind bottom login and use script but it's not working. When I show bottom it work but I don't want to show bottom please help me

```html
<tr>
  <td style="width:50%">
    <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text="ID:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox id="txtuserName" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
  <td style="width:50%">
    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtpassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" OnTextChanged="txtpassword_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id*=txtpassword]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {

      $('[id*=btnlogin]').click();
    }
  });
});
```

```csharp
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: whats your browser?

Comment: $('[id*=btnlogin]').click(); which it's ridiculous

Comment: IE and Chrome @AmirNorouzpour

Comment: You must use function for login and call it in your Enter key press

Comment: e.which doesn't work in IE try e.keyCode

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in button, you must set `ClientIDMode = "static"`

```
   $('#btnlogin').trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your button to

```
<asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" />
```

Then you can trigger the `btnlogin_Click` function with this in your javascript

```
_doPostBack('<%= btnlogin.UniqueID %>', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  // ...
}
```

```html
    <asp:TextBox  runat="server" id="txtpassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"   ></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" CssClass="hidden"/>
```

I have followed your advice script it work but code behind asp.net C# not responding.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('[id*=txtpassword]').keypress(function (e) {
             var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;

             if (keyCode == 13) {

                 
                 $('#btnlogin').trigger("click")
         }
     });
     });

  </script>
```